Chromium does not opens and neither able to uninstall
with

Ubuntu 24.04

Chromium v 124.0.6367.60 snap


installed Chromium Browser from App Store and now it suddenly stopped working; now it is not getting opened nor removed
tried to uninstall but it not getting uninstalled at all; below is the output of terminal
> $: sudo apt remove chromium --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'chromium-browser' instead of 'chromium'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

also tried
> $ sudo apt remove chromium-browser --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'chromium-browser' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


But it still there and interesting thing is when choose New Window with a temporary profile from pinned chromium icon then it opens but New Window option does not works.
also when type chromium in terminal it gives below output

[20317:20317:0427/142711.578699:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(353)] The profile appears to be in use by another Chromium process (2715) on another computer (recursive). Chromium has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted. If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chromium.
[20317:20317:0427/142711.578768:ERROR:message_box_dialog.cc(146)] Unable to show a dialog outside the UI thread message loop: Chromium - The profile appears to be in use by another Chromium process (2715) on another computer (recursive). Chromium has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted. If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chromium.

How to uninstall or how to fix this issue?

You seem to be using the apt command to remove a Snap package.
The correct way to remove a snap is sudo snap remove package_name
To get the correc name of the package to uninstall in terminal use snap list
It's FOSS reference
